# Parallel remote ssh to same machine

Tags: shell, ssh, expect

I want to run an expect script inside a shell script that connects to a remote machine by ssh, the objective is to do it in parallel method like this:

```
' #bin/bash    
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter1 > file1) &    
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter2 > file2) &    
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter3 > file3) &    
 wait
```

`
the expect script is something like this:

```
#/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh login@machine1
...code...
```

the expect script takes about 30 seconds to do the task and print the result.
Is it possible? Maybe it could work with different machines but with one unique machine I am not sure that the script can do 3 ssh connections to one unique machine in same time.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? Could you simply replace `&` with `;` and wait for each task to complete?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but I only get the results of the last expect script. And if I put ';' it works but it is not a parallel task anymore.

Comment: Can you redirect `stdout` in the `expect` scripts (`expect` has switches like `-d` but also more powerful `tcl` functions to handle output)? Does the work have to be done in parallel? When doing simple tasks that log to a file I have used `pssh` (a python tool) to make multiple connections without problems. I think `bash` ,`ssh` , `expect` or `&` is eating your output here and you might need to tell the script directly to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

Comment: Nice idea: I tried to see what is going on by printing the output and I realized that one of the expect script in the background could not do the connection because the script cannot get the password I put in the parameters in order to authenticate the ssh connection. As the first expect script that could get the password runs, the others wait for time out because its cannot get the password parameters. Maybe I should go back to the serial method which works but take more time.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the first two lines of the script from :

```
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter1 > file1) &
```

to:

```
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter1 > file1) 2>&1
```

does it help?

Comment: I will try to do the thing you advise but I would like to know what your proposition (`2>&1`) means.

Comment: It means redirect `stderr` to `stdout` check the `bash` or `sh` manual pages.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your explication. I have tried to do what you said but if I change the two first lines as you said, these lines are not executed in the background so they have no errors. So I tried to execute this code:                `(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter1 > file1 2>&1) & 
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter2 > file2 2>&1) &    
(expect_script_ssh_machine1.tcl parameter3 > file3) &    
 wait   `                     However I don't receive any error...